# Sum multidimensional array columns

Tags: php, arrays, columnsorting

I have to sum some columns of an multidimensional array, and i`m stucked for 3 days at it. My array is like this:

```
$items = [ 
   0 => [
     0 => [
       'category' => 'CATEGORY ONE',
       'goal' => 12,
       'reached' => '14',
       'points' => '148',
    ],
    1 => [
      'category' => 'CATEGORY TWO',
      'goal' => 12,
      'reached' => '14',
      'points' => '148',
    ]
   ],
   1 => [
     0 => [
       'category' => 'CATEGORY ONE',
       'goal' => 12,
       'reached' => '14',
       'points' => '148',
    ],
    1 => [
      'category' => 'CATEGORY TWO',
      'goal' => 12,
      'reached' => '14',
      'points' => '148',
    ]
   ]
];
```

i was no abble to parse this data to get the sum of values of each category so it have to return like this:

```
$items = [
 0 => [
   'category' => 'CATEGORY ONE',
   'goal' => 24,
   'reached' => '48',
   'points' => '296',
],
1 => [
  'category' => 'CATEGORY TWO',
  'goal' => 12,
  'reached' => '14',
  'points' => '296',
]];
```

Comment: How is `'reached' => '48'` calculated?

Comment: Post your code so we can find mistakes and help you fix it to achieve the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

This is not universal code but do just what you want

```
$result = [];
$categoriesData = [];
// aggregate data by category name
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $category) {
        $categoryName = $category['category'];
        if (!isset($categoriesData[$categoryName])) {
            $categoriesData[$categoryName] = [
                'goal' => 0,
                'reached' => 0,
                'points' => 0
            ];
        }
        foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === 'category') continue;
            $categoriesData[$categoryName][$key] += (int) $value;
        }
    }
}

// result data
foreach ($categoriesData as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = [
        'category' => $key,
        'goal' => (string) $value['goal'],
        'reached' => (string) $value['reached'],
        'points' => (string) $value['points']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$itemsFlattened = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $items);

$itemsSummed = [];
foreach ($itemsFlattened as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item['category'], $itemsSummed)) {
        $itemsSummed[$item['category']]['goal'] += $item['goal'];
        $itemsSummed[$item['category']]['reached'] += $item['reached'];
        $itemsSummed[$item['category']]['points'] += $item['points'];
    } else {
        $itemsSummed[$item['category']] = $item;
    }
}
$itemsSummed = array_values($itemsSummed);

print_r($itemsSummed);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => CATEGORY ONE
            [goal] => 24
            [reached] => 28
            [points] => 296
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => CATEGORY TWO
            [goal] => 24
            [reached] => 28
            [points] => 296
        )

)
```

Comment: tks dude! you saved my live!

Comment: @RichardFeliciano No problem :) If my answer helped you, don't forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)